# how to call a python function on click of submit in html using flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

''' hi I am trying to call my function on click of html button but I don't understand how to do it.My function is for emotion analysis of human when it is called it will open a window and web cam will be started for live emotion analysis.Here is my code with html code'''

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from video_tester_of_emotions import main_app

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/flask', methods=['Get', 'POST'])
def sample():
    if request.method == "POST":
        result = request.form
        #main_app() function of emotion analysis
    return render_template("hello.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
    Emotion Ananlysis
  </title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;text-align:center">
<h1 style="
color: aqua;
font-family: cursive;
font-size: 56px;
">welcome to "Emotion Analysis"</h1>

<img src="/static/images/emo.gif" width="500" height="300" border="5" alt="Human Emotions"/>

<h2 style="
color: aqua;
font-family: cursive;
font-size: 23px;">Click On Start To See Your Emotions</h2>
<form  action = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/flask" method = "POST">
<p><input type = "submit" value = "Start!" style="display: inherit; margin: auto; margin-top: 50px; 
font-size: 22px; background: cadetblue;"/></p>

</form>>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Javascript?

Comment: Are you getting any exception with your code?

Comment: I have't tried J.S, actually I have no idea of J.S

Answer (score 0):

Try to import redirect and then try below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from video_tester_of_emotions import main_app

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/flask', methods=['Get', 'POST'])
def sample():
    if request.method == "POST":
        result = request.form
        #main_app() function of emotion analysis
        return redirect('/flask')
    else:
         return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```